# Why won't my navigation bar allow me to click the link until it reaches a certain element?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've made a basic parallax website and I am looking to put a simple navigation bar on the top right of the screen. When I load up the website in my browser, the link (which at the moment is linked to #) won't allow me to click it until I reach the class `.section`. If it is touching any of the images that have the parallax effect, it becomes opaque, and won't allow me to click. I had a feeling it had something to do with bad placement, and even when I moved it around it seemed to have no effect. It also won't float to the right. Here is some of the HTML and CSS:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
 margin:0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.8em;
 color:#666;

}
.navbar {
 list-style: none;
 color:#779cd8;
 position:fixed;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 20px;

}
.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3{
 position:relative;
 opacity:0.70;
 background-position: center;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.pimg1 {
 background-image: url('../AlignedResonance/mountainsvg.svg');
 min-height: 100%;


}

.pimg2 {
 background-image: url('../AlignedResonance/tree.jpg');
 min-height: 400px;
}
.pimg3 {
 background-image: url('../AlignedResonance/lake.jpg');
 min-height: 400px;
}

.section {
 text-align:center;
 padding: 50px 80px;
}

.section-light {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color:#666;
}

.section-dark {
 background-color: #282e34;
 color:#ddd;
}

.ptext {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color:black;
 font-size: 27px;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.ptext .border {
 background-color: #111;
 color: #fff;
 padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Aligned Resonance</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../AlignedResonance/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="pimg1">
      <!-- class ptext -->
      <div class="ptext">
       <span>
        Aligned Resonance
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <section class="section section-light">
      <h2>Section One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </section>
     <div class="pimg2">
      <div class="ptext">
       <span class="border">
        Text 2
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <section class="section section-dark">
      <h2>Section One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </section>
     <div class="pimg3">
      <div class="ptext">
       <span class="border">
        Text 3
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>

     <section class="section section-dark">
      <h2>Section One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </section>
     <div class="pimg1">
      <div class="ptext">
       <span>
        Aligned Resonance
       </span>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry if I don't have a correct format etc., as I am new to HTML as well as this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the z-index for your navbar class:

```
.navbar {
    list-style: none;
    color:#779cd8;
    position:fixed;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```